# How to increase response area of getCurrentSeriesAndPoint()

Tags: android, achartengine

I am now using AchartEngine to paint a chart. When I try to use getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() function to get the current clicked datapoint, I find it is very hard to make it return not null. How can I increase the response area of getCurrentSeriesAndPoint()? Is this relative to the point size? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(sizeInPixels);
```